# Xamarin and play videos with FairPlay or other DRM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, video-streaming, azure-media-services

I'm trying to stream a content from `Azure Media Services`, but I can't get it to work, so I'm wondering if it's doable, and if so, how do I achieve it? The content is protected by `FairPlay`. Similar issues on Android and Windows.

I tried to use [Xamarin Media Player](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager) but it doesn't work with `FairPlay` because it requires an `ExoPlayer2` implementation which is not yet in the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible with the current version of the Xamarin Media Manager. Let me also correct the mistaken assumption about ExoPlayer2. ExoPlayer is a strictly Android only playback component, and so has nothing to do with FairPlay at all, as FairPlay is Apple only technology.

For FairPlay to work, you have to listen to events that are specific for FairPlay to handle the license exchange. Those do not seem to be implemented in Xamarin Media Manager as far as i can see. So you would have to do those platform specific implementations yourself. Information about these can be found on the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/).

For Android, you would likely want to go with Widevine, which is implemented in ExoPlayer. I can't find any documentation for Xamarin Media Manager on how to set that up either though.